# unable to install a module due to sql error message

Tags: php, sql, magento-1.7

I am following a free tutorial online from Magento U and have gotten to a stage where a module is being installed.

Currently I have spent about three hours trying different alternatives to overcome the Sql error (at line 1) I keep getting. I have even removed the Magento specific functions and run it in mysql workbench on a test db, where it worked.

The install file runs and I am faced with

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

error

I have also considered that I may have a file set up incorrectly elsewhere in my module, but am unable to see what is wrong. Finally I have also tried to enable more detailed sql error messaging in Magento but haven't had any luck

My code is as follows

Training/Animal/sql/training_animal_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS{$installer->getTable('training/animal')};
CREATE TABLE {$installer->getTable('training/animal')} (
    entity_id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    edible TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    comments TEXT NULL,
    updated_at DATETIME,
    created_at DATETIME
) Engine=InnoDB DEFAULT Charset=UTF8;
");

$installer->endSetup();
```

Training/Animal/etc/config.etc

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Training_Animal>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Training_Animal>
</modules>

<global>
    <models>
        <training>
            <class>Training_Animal_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>training_animal_resource</resourceModel>
        </training>
        <training_animal_resource>
            <class>Training_Animal_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <animal><table>training_animal_entity</table></animal>
            </entities>
        </training_animal_resource>
    </models>

    <resources>
        <training_animal_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Training_Animal</module>
                <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </training_animal_setup>
    </resources>
</global>

<frontend>
    <routers>
        <animal>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Training_Animal</module>
                <frontName>animal</frontName>
            </args>
        </animal>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

I also have three other files

Training/Animal/Model/Mysql4/Animal/Collection.php

Training/Animal/Model/Mysql4/Animal.php

Training/Animal/Model/Animal.php

but have not posted them due to the error message and to save space, if they are required, please let me know

Comment: never used magento, but generally you can **NOT** have multiple queries in a single `->exec()`-type call in PHP-mysql code. It's an anti-injection attack defense mechanism. e.g. issue your DROP and CREATE queries via two separate `->run()` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is this line:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS{$installer->getTable('training/animal')};
```

Add a space between `EXISTS` and `{$installer->getTable('training/animal')}`.